# Add custom Text Layout to Wiki library

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, wiki-pages

In SharePoint 2010 Foundation a wiki library have 8 text layouts (One column, One column with sidebar, etc..)
How can I add custom text layouts?

Answer (score 1):

You Can change Master Pages, and from this You Can change Layouts. You Can change Layouts in Microsoft Sharepoint Designer, or in Visual Studio.

And here You have a Example in Sharepoint:
http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/create-a-new-wiki-content-page-in-sharepoint-2010.html

And here is how to do this by Visual Studio:
http://www.sharepointeurope.com/blog/2012/4/6/how-to-modify-standard-%28non-enterprise%29-sharepoint-2010-wiki-page-layout